# React-Redux component test fails when using async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, mocha.js

I'm trying to test react-redux connected app which is having aync action to fetch data from API. But the test fails for some reason. what wrong i'm doing here?

> AssertionError: expected { length: 0 } to have a length of 1 but got 0

**posts.js(Redux Action)**

```
import instance from "./../config/axiosconfig";

export const postList = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return instance.get("/posts")
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data;
        return dispatch({
          type: "POST_LIST", posts
        });
      });
  };
};
```

**posts.js(React Component)**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {postList} from "../actions/posts";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Post extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.posts === undefined || this.props.posts.length === 0) {
      const {dispatch} = this.props;
      dispatch(postList());
    }
  }
  render() {
    let postLists = "";
    if (this.props.posts) {
      postLists = this.props.posts.map((list, i) => (
                    <li key = {i}>
                      {list.title}
                    </li>
                  ));
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>About</h2>
        <p>Services</p>
        <ol className="post-list">
          {postLists}
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Post.propTypes = {
  posts: PropTypes.array,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({ dispatch });

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { posts: state.PostReducer ? state.PostReducer.posts : [] };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Post);
```

**Post.test.js(Test for component)**

```
import React from "react";
import Post from "client/components/post";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import PostReducer from "client/reducers/posts";
import {mount, render, shallow} from 'enzyme'
import instance from "client/config/axiosconfig";
import { expect } from "chai";
import moxios from "moxios";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
let store;
let wrapper;

describe("Post Component", () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        moxios.install(instance);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        moxios.uninstall(instance);
    });

    it("has expected posts lists listed", async () => {
        store = setupStore();
        const payload = [{
            body: "TEST",
            id: 1,
            title: "Test Title"
        }];
        moxios.wait(() => {
            const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
            request.respondWith({
                status: 200,
                response: payload
            });
        });
        wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><Post/></Provider>);
        expect(wrapper.find('.post-list li')).to.have.length(1);  
    });

    function setupStore() {
        return createStore(
          combineReducers({ PostReducer }),
          applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The request which you have stubbed may still be pending by the time make an assertion.

Try the following:

```
it("has expected posts lists listed", async () => {
    store = setupStore();
    const payload = [{
        body: "TEST",
        id: 1,
        title: "Test Title"
    }];

    const promise = moxios.wait(() => {
        const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
        request.respondWith({
            status: 200,
            response: payload
        });
    });

    const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><Post/></Provider>);

    await promise;

    wrapper.update(); // May not be necessary

    expect(wrapper.find('.post-list li')).to.have.length(1);
});
```

Comment: I tried as you explained. but still getting same error